# Transpose and add new record in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer_name = 'Alex' THEN item END) AS by_Alex,   
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer_name = 'Bob' THEN item END) AS by_Bob, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer_name = 'Jim' THEN item END) AS by_Jim
FROM sales;
```

Outputs this result
[image: Outputs this result]

How can I arrange this code to transpose as a matrix (w/2 columns "Name" and "Count")
and add a new row called "by_Christian" by summing up "by_Bob" (2) and "by_Alex" (3) and add 5 under "Count" column?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you simply want aggregation:

```
select name, count(*) as num_items, count(distinct item) as num_distinct_items
from sales
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation and `UNION ALL` as follows:

```
select name, count(distinct item) as cnt
  from sales
 where name in ('Alex','Bob','Jim')
group by name
UNION ALL
select 'Christian' AS name, 
        count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer_name = 'Alex' THEN item END) 
        + count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer_name = 'Bob' THEN item END) as cnt
  from sales
 where name in ('Alex','Bob');
```